# Is there something similar to MobileSubstrate for android?

Tags: android

I would like something similar to MobileSubstrate, but for Android instead of iOS.
Does that exist?

If not, is it even possible to make something like it for java?

Comment: You can't hook & replace Java functions since there are no function pointers, so probably no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saurik has announced CydiaSubstrate for Android devices supported on versions 2.3 through 4.2, including Kindle Fire, CyanogenMod, and Intel. You need to root your device first in order for it to work. You can read more on [CydiaSubstrate For Android](http://veryrite.com/2013/05/15/cydiasubstrate-for-android/) and download it from [CydiaSubstrate](http://www.cydiasubstrate.com/download/com.saurik.substrate.apk) or [GooglePlay Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.saurik.substrate).

Comment: Yeah I also saw that yesterday. Very cool!

Answer (score -2):

MobileSubstrate is a framework added after a jailbreak is done , it's done by Saurik .
More info here :http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/MobileSubstrate

In Android and if we want to push the comparison to the limit we have rooted phones with unlocked bootrom , after that you can create/compile your own rom with your functions.

Or just make a flashable zip to replace some files or execute some internal code .

I hope that it did answer your questions

Comment: This doesn't say if there is something similar to MobileSubstrate for Android for injecting into apps and changing functions/methods

Comment: well android is a java based OS , all android apps even native apps are already complied(apk) and executed by the DalvicVM , so to be able to do the same "hook" it's kind of reverse engineering . I'm not an iOS expert but it seems lightly different from android .

Comment: Doesn't answer anything.